# CSS border-right doesn't rendering correctly

Tags: html, css

I have a menu, when the menu item is active it should have a border to the right, the issue is that the border is doesn't render correctly, please notice the bottom edge of the border.

This image shows the issue:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3G45G.jpg

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2yj3hyqm/5/ (See full screen for better view)

CSS code:

```
.border {
   border-right:4px solid #000;
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: What is your intended result here? What you are showing is indeed a button with a border on the right.

Comment: It's because of your `border-bottom`. If you remove it it works fine. What you could do instead is use a pseudo element instead of a border

Comment: @Antiga yes it shows a border but the issue is that the edge of it appears distored.

Comment: just because the `border-bottom` overlapping ur `border-right`

Comment: just try to match the `border-color` with each other that works.

Comment: @shadeed9 I see it now. I need glasses. :(

Comment: Borders union are that way like diagonal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, the problem is the bottom border overlaping the right one. So, a possible solution is to "fake" a border using `:after` pseudo, placing it at the right of the element:

[**Updated JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2yj3hyqm/6/)

```
.border {
    position: relative;
}

.border:after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 4px;
    background: black;
    content: "\00a0"; /* invisible content */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The rendering is correct.

Take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vy5rpnL2/):

[image]

```
border: 10px solid black;
border-right-color: red;
border-bottom-color: blue;
border-left-color: green;
```

Note how the borders meet at the corners. Your menu items have a thick right border and a thin bottom border. The way borders meet at the corners the thick right border looks slightly crooked at the bottom. Try and remove the bottom border and see how the right border gets straight again.

You can try nesting elements in the menu item and apply the `border-bottom` and `border-right` to different elements or use a pseudo element to fix the appearance.

Answer (score 1):

Borders meet at angles so you would have to use an alternative for the right border

A `box-shadow` would work quite well

[**JSfiddle Comparison**](http://jsfiddle.net/kqL3q378/1/) (exaggerated)

**HTML**

```
<div class="border"> </div>

<div class="shadow">  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.border,
.shadow {
    background-color: grey;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid lightgrey;
}
.border{

    border-right: 20px solid black;
}

.shadow {
    box-shadow: 10px 0 0px 0 black;
}
```